# PDT Eclipse PHP: newly installed, unable to run test with php server, no execution enviroment

Tags: php, eclipse

I just downloaded and installed (Oxygen) PDT Eclipse PHP which boasts a built-in PHP server.  When I go to run my test.php file, I select:

```
  Run As -> 1. Run on Server
```

Which brings up the following dialog box:

[image: 1st dialogue box]

The option "Choose an existing server" is grayed out.  I then press the Next button and get:

[image: dialog 2 and 3]

Here I select the "Installed PHP executables" button, which brings up the second dialogue below the first in the previous image.   I select php7.1 or 7.0, but it does not "seem to stick", also when selected under the Eclipse top level menu:

```
 Window->Preferences->PHP->Installed PHPs->Execution Environments
```

it does not "seem to stick" (choice is not remembered).

As such, when I go to fill in the "PHP Executables" drop down, nothing is listed (totally empty), and I never get the "Finish" button to go active.

Is this a bug in Eclipse?  I can't imagine they didn't test such basic functionality adding in a built-in server (supposedly).  Suggestions or workarounds? Note the Eclipse PHP is fairly fast to download if you wish to try.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The *Eclipse for PHP Developers* is shipped with a built-in server that can run PHP. But the so-called ***PHP Built-in Server* requires a locally installed PHP** executalbe:

- **[Download](http://php.net/downloads.php) and install PHP**
- In ***Window > Preferences: PHP > Installed PHPs*** click ***Add...*** and fill in the fields to make the installed PHP from the previous step known to Eclipse PDT

Note, if multiple installed PHPs support the same PHP version, in the ***Execution Environments*** preference page can be selected which PHP should be used by default. But if no compatible interpreter is shown in the box on the right, it means that the PHP executable for the selected version on the left is missing.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  Under the php folder I downloaded there are 4 executables at the top level: php.exe, php-cgi.exe, phpdbg,exe, and php-win.exe.   Which one(s) of these get used?  I'm on a Windows 10 box BTW.

Comment: In the _New PHP Executable_ dialog enter the php folder (not an .exe file) into the field _Executable path_.

Comment: ... hmm ... yeah I tried that, that dialogue window has fields at the top called  "Name" and "Executable Path:", with a "Browse" button for the latter.  HOWEVER, IT WILL NOT ALLOW ONE TO SELECT A FOLDER, ONLY AN EXECUTABLE.  Would you please examine your setting more closely, perhaps provide a picture if necessary.  Thanks for your help.